# Checking multiple zero

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a variable has more than one zero. It seems php treats multiple zeros as one zero. For example, the following code always returns true no matter how many zeros the variable has:

```
    $input = 0000;//or "0000"
    if($input==00) echo "true"; 
    else echo "false";
```

My question is : How can I make the above code return true only if it has the exact number of zero in the if statement?
 Thanks

Comment: You are confusing strings and integers.

Comment: `0` is equal to `0` no matter if it's `00000` or `0000000000000` or `5-(1+4)`

Comment: `$input` comes from... ?

Comment: @zerkms But the result is the same whether the variable is a string or an integer.

Comment: @FadelMS: nope, it cannot be the same. Provide the correspondent code with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your `$input` is a decimal integer. Therefore, `0` does in fact equal `00000`.

You need to define it as a string and then compare with other strings.

```
$input = "0000";
if( $input === "00" ) { echo "yes"; } else { echo "no"; }
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make the above code return true only if it has the exact number of zero in the if statement?

Use strings.

Integers is the only data of the number, not its presentation. So `0000` equals to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Use strings instead of numbers

```
$input = "00000";
// This searches for 0 extra zeros on the left
if(strpos($input,"0")==0 && $input!=="0"){
    echo "true";
}
else{
   echo "false";
}
```

Comment: "return true only if it has the **exact** number of zero"

Comment: And how do you specify the count of numbers here?

Comment: this will fail if $input value is =0

Comment: He's wants to return true only if there are extra zeros not if it's only one 0

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $input = "0000";
    if(strcmp($input,"0000")==0) {echo "they match";} 
    else {echo "They dont";}

?>
```

Comment: Curious, why did you prefer `strcmp` over `==` here?

Comment: @zerkms Lusitanian already suggested that solution, i just presented an alternative possibility aswell. Also it will work with === but not ==

Comment: "Also it will work with === but not ==" --- it will work with `==` ;-)

Comment: nopes it won't :) with that it will say 0000 is equal to 00. Not atleast in 5.1